# Android - does setting the text of a textview call invalidate on all other views in parent?

Tags: android, view, textview, hierarchy

I have a textview that I use to display debugging info for gps over a custom map. I noticed that when the text changes the zoom-able imageview that I use gets reset. Is this because invalidate is getting called up the view hierarchy? I have my two views inside of a framelayout. I was wondering if I just put my textview inside a relativelayout and then put that into the framelayout if that would get rid of this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a time clock on screen that would kick off an invalidate every second when the text was changed.  If the TextView uses wrap_content then it will invalidate the layout ewhen the text is changed.  If you make the TextView's size fixed, then it doesn't need to invalidate itself when the text changes because it's size in the view hierarchy won't affect anything else.

Comment: ahhh I knew it was something goofy like that I was forgetting. Thanks :) when five minutes passes Ill accept this as the answer.